# CSS background-image giving mixed content warning over SSL

Tags: css, ssl, background-image

I've tried numerous methods to load my CSS background images over SSL without resulting in the mixed content warning.

On this page for example:
https://www.statcentric.com/login/default.aspx

You can see that the message is coming up.

For the logo (logo.png), I've tried using the protocol-less method like so:

```
span#logo
{
    background: url(//www.statcentric.com/images/logo.png) no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
}
```

For the background (bg.jpg), I've tried using a relative path like so:

```
body
{
    color: #191919;
    background: #f2f2f2 url(../../images/bg.jpg) repeat-x top;
}
```

However, as you'll see, both of these images are still being flagged as mixed content.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried using `https://`? I've never used SSL on a website, so this might be a stupid recommendation...

Comment: Using https:// results in a lag when the http:// site loads. Keep in mind that these images are used on every page.

Comment: Ahh, that makes a bit more sense. Maybe defining a separate stylesheet for the HTTP page will work? I'm going to look for how banks or other sites with a HTTP and a HTTPS version do it...

Comment: I've looked at how a few people do it and the two methods I mentioned above seem to be pretty good solutions for most. I'm not sure why it's not working for me. Using another stylesheet for https (or moreso just for the elements with background-image) would be a pain, so I'm trying to look for other options :)

Comment: Are the images uploaded to the SSL site directory? Might be a silly question but I've seen it happen before.

Comment: What do you mean Dan? The images are stored in one location served over both http:// and https://

I'm using IIS and I've never had to do anything to get SSL working on the server once the certificate is applied.

Comment: Yeah this seems strange.  I work on a site that uses SSL extensively and I've always just pathed my images from the root... "url('/img/myimagehere.png')" and I've never had a problem with it. Maybe a server side issue?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried pathing your images from the root? ex. url('/images/bg.jpg')

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your tolerance for older browsers, you might look into making your images inline with base64 encoding; data URIs in other words.

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme#CSS
- http://www.websiteoptimization.com/speed/tweak/inline-images/

It does make your css files bigger and maintenance harder, so you'll have to weigh the size of css file versus the cost of the SSL request.  For small images, I usually find the size of the css file is the better way to go.

The other option I know if two different css files; one for ssl and one for not.